# Email Client Software that Limits Number of Downloaded Emails?

Tags: mail.app, email, office-365

I'm searching for an email client (MacOS - I'm running Catalina) that limits the number of downloaded emails onto my macbook. Such as limiting to say 10000 emails, or limiting to emails in last 30 days. I don't want to bog my machine with too many emails so I currently use the Office 365 web client. It would be great if I could use a local email client, which would provide more features than the web interface I'm currently using.

Apparently the mail app doesn't have an option to limit the number of downloads. Is there another email client for MacOS that will allow control of how many emails are downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) - a popular free and open source email client has a feature to limit email downloads by days, weeks, months, size etc. and is available [for macOS](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/) too.

See this answer here to set the limits - [How to prevent Thunderbird to download all emails after fresh install?](https://askubuntu.com/a/939719)